# remove lines where values are less than a constant in a column

Tags: bash, awk

`cat data.txt`

sr  var value lat lon depth time unit type

> 1. T  -9999.99  31.230  25.462  0  2012102921  degC  BUOY
> 2. T  20.0757   42.123  15.552  3  2012052921  degC  BUOY
> 3. T  -9999.99  37.523  19.122  0  20120511502143    degC  BUOY
> 4. T  20.3503   37.523  25.462  3  20120530    degC  BUOY
> 5. T  -9999.99  09.523  25.462  0  201205300342  degC  BUOY
> 6. T  20.3198   32.523  21.462  3  2012053003  degC  BUOY
> 7. T  -9999.99  12.523  19.333  0  2012053006  degC  BUOY
> 8. T  20.387    15.523  25.462  3  20120530063421  degC  BUOY
> 9. S  -9999.99  37.523  15.466  0  2012053009  psu   BUOY
> 10. T  20.5518   34.523  30.462  3  2014093009  degC  BUOY
> 11. T  -9999.99  39.523  35.462  0  2012053012  degC  BUOY
> 12. T  20.7166   31.523  24.462  3  2012053012  degC  BUOY

I want to remove the lines

where lat (in column 4) is less than lets say `minLat=29.1` and greater than `maxLat=35.9`

where lon (in column 5) is less than `minLon=22.5` and greater than `maxLon=41.7`

where time (in column 7) is less than `minTime=20120512` and greater than `maxTime=20120917`.

In column 7, the times are `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format. But sometimes its `20120512` (no hours, minutes and seconds) and sometimes its `20120718305232` (minutes and seconds are there). the `${minTime}` and `${maxTime}` are always in fixed length (`YYYYMMDD`). Or change `20120512` to `20120512000000` in column 7 to filter easily.

Any awk solution?
Thanks.

Comment: post the expected output and get rid of those leading line numbers you added if they are such.

Comment: "lat (in column 4)" cannot be "less than ... minLat=..." and "greater than maxLat=..." if `maxLat >= minLat` as your example quotes... Similar impossibilities exist in your other proposed constraints... Perhaps you meant "or" instead of "and"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, awk must be able to do this. Try something like:

```
awk '{ if ($3 >= 29.1 && $3 <= 35.9 &&
           $4 >= 22.5 && $4 <= 41.7 &&
           substr($6, 0, 8) >= "20120512" && substr($6, 0, 8) <= "20120917")
         print($0); }' < inputfile
```

This will print but one line from your example:

```
T 20.7166 31.523 24.462 3 2012053012 degC BUOY
```

Note, I had your example lines start with T or S, not with your numbering 1, 2, etc. Hence the conditions start at $3 etc. The dates are filtered by examining only the first 8 characters (using `substr()`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Karel, it works well. I added more conditions and also worked.